# cp -l instead of cp -s does not work?

Tags: command-line, symbolic-link, cp, hard-link

I have a folder symlink to core files and a folder with my improvements like this:

- core/ -> /some/distant/root/directory/core/

  - script_a.py
  - special/script_b.py
  - special/script_c.py
- core-improvements/

  - special/script_b.py

What I want to do is to create third directory called improved-core/ (using bash script), where there is going to be the contents of core-improvements/ and recursively linked contents of core/ (I mean /some/distant/root/directory/core/):

- improved-core/

  - script_a.py -> /some/distant/root/directory/core/script_a.py
  - special/script_b.py (from core-improvements/)
  - special/script_c.py -> /some/distant/root/directory/core/special/script_c.py

If I create it by hand using symlink to script_a.py, script_a.py calls script_b.py from the /some/distant/root/directory/core/special/ directory, not the one in improved-core/special/ directory.

So I suppose the hard links are needed here?

---

So far I created the following bash script, that works nicely for me, but it creates the symlinks instead of hardlinks:

```
cp -r core-improvements/ improved-core/ &&
cp -LnrsT core/ improved-core/
```

Then I tried to create hard links instead of symlinks by switching -LnrsT to -LnrlT, but I get the following errors:

cp: cannot create hard link 'improved-core/script_a.py' to '/some/distant/root/directory/core/script_a.py': Operation not permitted

I'm now completely lost how to solve the issue.

Comment: Are the two directories in same filesystem? Try to run `df -h .` in each of them to verify that. You can't make hard-links between filesystems.

Comment: Yes, they are in the same filesystem (all df outputs equals)

Comment: Update: the same issue is for ln vs. ln -s

Comment: ln vs ln -s is also hard-links versus soft/symbolic-links ... can you hard-link file a to file b in the same directory ?

Comment: Yes, I can create hard links inside any of these directories and when I log in (become) as /some/distant/root/directory/core/ user, I can ln here as well. I just can't ln in /some/distant/root/directory/core/ when I'm logged in (become) as core-improvements/ user

Comment: If you have to change user to have rights to create links, you might have to run the command with elevated (super user) rights, by running `sudo ln ....`

Comment: I'm not sure how. The whole thing happens in cloud and there is no sudo command. logging-in and out as a different user is handled by `become` command

Comment: Okay, I ended up setting git repo in source and git clone in destination, but this solution applied inside one filesystem is not ideal (it works though)